# assertEqual is not working

Tags: java, rest, testing, junit

I'm parsing 2 REST services and then comparing there responses in Java. I can see the json responses returned from both services.

I'm using assertEqual(actual,expected) to validate key values of both services  . I'm forcing the wrong expected values but the assertion doesn't fail.

sample:

```
String base_url_1= "http://url1.";
String base_url_11= "http://url11.";

@Test
public void comparing () throws JSONException, IOException{    

    JSONArray json1 = jsonReader.readJsonFromUrl(base_url_1);
    JSONArray json11 = jsonReader.readJsonFromUrl(base_url_11);

    if (json1 != null) { 
        for (int i=0;i<json1.length();i++){
            for (int j=0;j<json11.length();j++) { 

                JSONObject oneObject = json1.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject oneObject11 = json11.getJSONObject(j);

                Object   name= oneObject.get("name");
                Object   name11= oneObject11.get("name");

                //System.out.println(json1.getJSONObject(j));
                //System.out.println(oneObject11);

                assertThat(name.equals("test"));
                assertEqual(oneObject.get("name"),oneObject11.get("address"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code doesn't fail. even though values are different.

Comment: Provide the code and what values you are forcing the variables to.

Comment: I am willing to wager that `foo` and `bar` are either both `null` or in fact _are_ identical, at least according to the `equals()` method.

Comment: Seems the test itself didn't ran. In JUnit tests you need either annotate @Test or begin the method name with test. Please paste the whole method with the method signature.

Comment: are you sure the assertions are run?  is `json1` really != null ?

Comment: Yes that is not null, I ran the code in debug mode.

Comment: Can you print the values of `oneObject.get("name")` and `oneObject11.get("address")`?

Comment: Yes I can print both values, clearly they are different. but Junit is showing the test passed.

Comment: Could you provide the `import` statements that you use? I'm only aware of `assertEquals` method on `Assert` class. Not an `assertEqual`...

Comment: import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Test;

Comment: There should have been some static imports... Add `import org.junit.Assert;` And then try with `Assert.assertThat()` and `Assert.assertEquals()` & see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Awesome Vineet! It works as expected! Thanks Alot